# Error: Unable to establish connection with R session

Tags: r, rstudio

I am having trouble pulling down data sets from the web (https://api.fda.gov) FDA API. The connection is fine and it appears generate more than 4000 JSON records. The problem is, when it is done, R gives me the below error and I am no longer able to do anything in RStudio - I basically have to force quit. I've seen references to similar issues, but haven't been able to find a solution.

> Error: Unable to establish connection with R session

Comment: try storing the large dataset in a new environment instead of dataframe or list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using RStudio? There is a problem with RStudio and pulling large data sets. See here: [Wang's Tech Blog](https://rachelshuyanwang.wordpress.com/2015/01/26/troubleshooting-unable-to-establish-connection-with-r-session/) and here: [RStudio Support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200751563-Error-Unable-to-establish-connection-with-R-session-OS-X-mavrics-rstudio-0-98-484).

I suggest just using R in the terminal when you run scripts that pull large data-sets.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve all problems by deactivating/deinstalling the antivirus software (Avast)

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this error. Uninstalling avast did not work for me. I uninstalled r and r studio and reinstalled r and r studio and this solved my problem.